# How to persist data in twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-node

Maybe it's a bit of a novice question, but I need to persist a user's data, through a full conversation with the autopilot. There exists in twilio something like Dialogflow for save data?

https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/save-data

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Twilio Sync to store state.

Twilio Sync
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync/api